# Trouble reading messages with AT+CMGL="ALL"

Tags: at-command

I'm programming a modem using AT commands. When I execute `AT+CMGL="ALL"`, sometimes, it does not return anything. At other times, it returns the list of messages.

Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on whether the phone is configured to PDU mode or text mode. The [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) standard says:

```
<stat> integer type in PDU mode (default 0), or string type in text mode (default
"REC UNREAD"); indicates the status of message in memory; defined values:
       0 "REC UNREAD"   received unread message (i.e. new message)
       1 "REC READ"     received read message
       2 "STO UNSENT"   stored unsent message (only applicable to SMs)
       3 "STO SENT"     stored sent message (only applicable to SMs)
       4 "ALL"          all messages (only applicable to +CMGL command)
```

So you should run

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CMGL="ALL"
```

(Possibly also `AT+CPMS` to be sure of which storage you are reading from ([notice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746283/23118) that you  probably want to specify both `<mem1>` and `<mem2`))