# Trouble setting "Preferred Message Storage" with AT+CPMS on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: at-command

When connecting Samsung Galaxy S via USB to Hyperterminal, I cannot retrieve any messages from the modem. The commands `AT` and `AT+CMGF=1` work, and `AT+CPMS=?` returns different memories available.

But when I try to execute the following command: `AT+CPMS="SM"` (or any other memory) I get: `cms error 321`. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Additional info:

```
AT+CPMS=?

+CPMS: ("BM","ME","SM","SR"),("ME","SM"),("BM","ME","SM","SR")

AT+CPMS="SM"

+CMS ERROR: 321
```

Comment: Where is AT+CMPI documented?  Have you tried specifying the memory with AT+CPMS?  Also +CMGR to read an SMS, +CMGL for a list, etc?  Details for use are at http://www.developershome.com/sms/

Comment: Very much sorry, when I typed the question I accidently wrote AT+CMPI. Of course that the command is AT+CPMS="SM". AT+CMGL and AT+CMGR don't work because a memory is not selected (gives ERROR...). Thank you very much for the comment!

Comment: What's the exact output from AT+CPMS=? and AT+CPMS?

Comment: Can't tell right know, I will post in few hours. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries.  You can add more information yourself directly to your original question.

Comment: Have added the information

Comment: AT+CPMS? will tell you what the current value is.

Comment: When trying out AT commands, usually do: (1)find out what the possible values are, (2) find out the current value (3) set your new value (4) check the new current value.

Answer (score 2):

From [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) `+CMS ERROR 321` means `invalid memory index`.

The `AT+CPMS` command has three parameters with official syntax `AT+CPMS=<mem1>[,<mem2>[,<mem3>]]`. However I think that the problem is that the phone chokes at having different `<mem1>` and `<mem2>` values.

So although the official valid syntax would allow for only giving `<mem1>` I suspect the syntax to actually be `AT+CPMS=<mem1>,<mem2>[,<mem3>]` on some phones due to some implementation issue, (possibly limited to just certain values/combinations for `<memN>`). As far as I remember this was the case for phones from SonyEricsson, but I have always given both `<mem1>` and `<mem2>` with the same value for many years, so my memory might be a bit rusty.

I do think it is might be the case for other phones as well; if you search for example use cases of `AT+CPMS` you will see that giving both is more common than just `<mem1>` (and frankly I have a hard time imagining scenarios where you really want to read/delete from one storage and write/send from another storage). Given that my memory is correct, the described behaviour should be applicable for your phone as well since Samsung uses software from ST-Ericsson in their Galaxy phones.