# Receiving text messages with ZTE MF831 not working

Tags: node.js, serial-port, at-command

I got myself a ZTE MF831 modem to do some automations over text messages. I changed the mode to factory mode, so I can send instructions over `/dev/ttyUSB2 115200` (using screen or node with serialport).

**Sending text messages works just fine.** I receive the text on my personal phone. But when I send a message back (already sent several) I cannot read them. **The folders on my modem are always empty.** Even though I receive a notification like `+CMTI: ME,0`.

These are the commands I send:

```
ATZ           -> OK
AT+CMGF=1     -> OK
AT+CPMS=?
  -> +CPMS: ("ME","MT","SM","SR"),("ME","MT","SM","SR"),("ME","MT","SM","SR")
  -> OK

AT+CPMS="SM"  -> +CPMS: 0,20,0,100,0,100
              -> OK
AT+CMGL="ALL" -> OK

AT+CPMS="ME"  -> +CPMS: 0,100,0,100,0,100
              -> OK
AT+CMGL="ALL" -> OK

AT+CPMS="MT"  -> +CPMS: 0,100,0,100,0,100
              -> OK
AT+CMGL="ALL" -> OK

AT+CPMS="SR"  -> +CPMS: 0,100,0,100,0,100
              -> OK
AT+CMGL="ALL" -> +CMS ERROR: 500
```

As you can see, there is always no text available. **So I swapped my SIM card to another phone and tried again: I receive messages indeed.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tested a little further and realized that when sending `AT+CPMS=?` I receive

```
+CPMS: ("ME","MT","SM","SR"),("ME","MT","SM","SR"),("ME","MT","SM","SR")
```

That tells me that I can set **3 preferred folders** (since there are 3 bracket blocks).

So I thought, I set all to "SM":

```
AT+CPMS="SM","SM","SM"
```

I then flush the thing with `ATZ` and `AT` (I don't know which one actually does this).

---

Now when I receive a text I see `+CMTI: SM,<old used space>`.

Comment: Yes, you should always [set at least both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746283/23118) `<mem1>` and `<mem2>` to the same value.