# Hi, when I try to run the following command: AT+CPMS="SM" (or any other memory) I get: cms error . Can anyone help me? Thanks

Tags: gsm, at-command, nokia

AT+CPMS=?

+CPMS: (),(),()

AT+CPMS="SM"

ERROR

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where using extended error reporting, `AT+CMEE=2`, very likely will give some hint on what the problem is rather than just "something went wrong", aka `ERROR`.

I strongly suspect the problem to be [not giving both `<mem1>` and `<mem2>` values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746283/23118).